# Android NDK produce massive .so file which has only one function

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I get **800KB** `.so` file when build this `cpp` file with android NDK:

**test.cpp**

```cpp
int *test() {
    return new int;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
set(SOURCE_FILES test.cpp)
add_library(native_util SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

It's unacceptable size for me. Correct me if anything wrong about this.

---

I just realized when  I remove `new int` in `test.cpp` , then `.so` file size reduce to 80KB... hmm, how possible???

**test.cpp** which produce **80KB** `.so` file

```cpp
int test() {
    return 0;
}
```

---

My NDK version:

```
Android/sdk/ndk-bundle 
➜ cat source.properties 
Pkg.Desc = Android NDK
Pkg.Revision = 19.2.5345600
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply speaking, it is up to how many needed external symbols included into your shared library.

> I just realized when I remove new int in test.cpp , then .so file size reduce to 80KB... hmm, how possible???

This is possible. Because, below code

```cpp
// test.cpp
int *test() {
    return new int;
}
```

the `new` operator depends on other C++ libraries, when you build your `test.cpp`, the shared library, e.g. `test_with_new_operator.so` file will add those external symbol information for future usage during the linking phase, e.g. the `std::xxx` symbols needed. When you change it to

```cpp
// test.cpp which produce 80KB .so file
int test() {
    return 0;
}
```

it won't depend on the C++ std libraries and those symbol information won't be added into your `test_without_new_operator.so` and you will see a smaller size.

For example, when you issue command

```
nm --demangle ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so
```

the `test_with_new_operator.so` includes below symbol information (**more external symbol information!!!**)

```
0001ba44 r GCC_except_table0
0001b668 r GCC_except_table0
0001b698 r GCC_except_table1
0001ba98 r GCC_except_table1
0001b568 r GCC_except_table1
0001b9b8 r GCC_except_table1
...
0000622c T std::bad_array_length::bad_array_length()
0000623c T std::bad_array_length::~bad_array_length()
000061c8 T std::bad_array_length::~bad_array_length()
000061c8 T std::bad_array_length::~bad_array_length()
...
00017222 t std::__ndk1::__vector_base<std::__ndk1::vector<__cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::string_pair<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::malloc_alloc<char> > >, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::short_alloc<__cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::string_pair<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::malloc_alloc<char> > >, 4096u> >, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::short_alloc<std::__ndk1::vector<__cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::string_pair<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::malloc_alloc<char> > >, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::short_alloc<__cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::string_pair<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::malloc_alloc<char> > >, 4096u> >, 4096u> >::~__vector_base()
0001867a t std::__ndk1::__vector_base<std::__ndk1::vector<std::__ndk1::vector<__cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::string_pair<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::malloc_alloc<char> > >, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::short_alloc<__cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::string_pair<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::malloc_alloc<char> > >, 4096u> >, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::short_alloc<std::__ndk1::vector<__cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::string_pair<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::malloc_alloc<char> > >, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::short_alloc<__cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::string_pair<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::malloc_alloc<char> > >, 4096u> >, 4096u> >, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::short_alloc<std::__ndk1::vector<std::__ndk1::vector<__cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::string_pair<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::malloc_alloc<char> > >, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::short_alloc<__cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::string_pair<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::malloc_alloc<char> > >, 4096u> >, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::short_alloc<std::__ndk1::vector<__cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::string_pair<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::malloc_alloc<char> > >, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::short_alloc<__cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::string_pair<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::malloc_alloc<char> > >, 4096u> >, 4096u> >, 4096u> >::~__vector_base()
0000e304 t std::__ndk1::__split_buffer<__cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::string_pair<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, 
...
```

But, `test_without_new_operator.so` won't have these symbols and the library size is smaller.

---

**Edit #1**

> It's unacceptable size for me. Correct me if anything wrong about this.

You don't need to worry too much about this, because when you package those shared libraries into the final apk, the unnecessary symbols and debug information will be stripped (gradle task `app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease` will do this job) and your final apk size actually is much smaller than what is unacceptable for you.

Also, cross check below references if you have interests:

- [How to decrease the size of android native shared libaries (.so files)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51784882/how-to-decrease-the-size-of-android-native-shared-libaries-so-files/51814290#51814290)
- [Android NDK path variable for "strip" command in CMake build tool chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53409479/android-ndk-path-variable-for-strip-command-in-cmake-build-tool-chain/53422788#53422788)
- [how to prevent cmake from stripping the created shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53841991/how-to-prevent-cmake-from-stripping-the-created-shared-library/53861485#53861485)

Comment: Yeah, the `.so` file packed inside release apk only has 100KB (zipped size ~40KB)